# Codenameone : Custom Component doesn't get right height

Tags: graphics, codenameone

I was trying to print **rectangle** in **Codenameone**.

```
fun showCustomForm() {
    val hi = Form("", BorderLayout())
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, getGreenLine())
    hi.show()
}

fun getGreenLine(): Component {
    return object : Component() {
        override fun paint(g: Graphics) {
            println("Graphics Printing starts")
            g.color = 0x00ff00
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height)
        }

        override fun calcPreferredSize(): Dimension {
            return Dimension(1, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

As showing above, the rectangle is supposed to have a width of 1 and height of 20

The height seems to be correct but the width goes across the screen.

What is the right way to **display the rectangle with the correct dimension**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Kotlin, however... in this example, try to replace `BorderLayout()` with `BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER)` to give to the component its preferred size.

In general, the layout managers can or cannot use the preferred size, see: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html

For example, `FlowLayout` always gives a component its preferred size; `BoxLayout.y()` always gives a component its preferred height, but using the maximum available width; etc.